# Increment/decrement value of one of many similar text input with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, function, textinput

The fallowing table has many identical text inputs...

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#" id="plus"><img src="plus.png" width="12" height="12" /></a>
      <input type="text" value="0" />
      <a href="#" id="minus"><img src="minus.png" width="12" height="12" /></a>
    </td>
    .
    .

    <td>
      <a href="#" id="plus"><img src="plus.png" width="12" height="12" /></a>
      <input type="text" value="0" />
      <a href="#" id="minus"><img src="minus.png" width="12" height="12" /></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and the fallowing jQuery script should increment/decrement the value of its closet text input...

```
 $("#plus").click(function(){
   var text = $(this).next(":text");
   text.val(parseInt(text.val(), 10) + 1);
 });

$("#minus").click(function(){
   var text = $(this).prev(":text");
   aux.val(parseInt(aux.val(), 10) - 1);
 });
```

the problem is that the script only works fine on the first pair of links of the table, incrementing and decrementing the value of its closest text input by one, and the rest of the remaining pairs of links don't change the value of its closest text input and whats even worse, the links propagate to the `home/jthernandez/Desktop/test.html#` url when they are clicked on.

I'm not really sure whats going on here but the idea is that each pair of +, - links changes the value of its next(), prev() text input respectively. Any suggestions would be great. Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't reuse the same `id`, it's invalid html and can lead to all kinds of problems.

Comment: Rookie mistake indeed... thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close.  As others have mentioned, you cannot have the same ID more than once.  IDs are unique, to *IDentify* a single element.  JavaScript will only look until it finds one, and then stop.  Classes are used to group common elements.  Use a class and your code should work fine (minus a typo in your javascript):

HTML:

```
<td>
    <a href="#" class="plus"><img src="plus.png" width="12" height="12" /></a>
    <input type="text" value="0" />
    <a href="#" class="minus"><img src="minus.png" width="12" height="12" /></a>
</td>
```

JS (you have a typo in minus, creating `text`, but using `aux`):

```
$(".plus").click(function(){
    var text = $(this).next(":text");
    text.val(parseInt(text.val(), 10) + 1);
});

$(".minus").click(function(){
    var text = $(this).prev(":text");
    text.val(parseInt(text.val(), 10) - 1);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/bfM9Z/

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for the jsfiddle link, that sure will be quite handy in the future...

Answer (score 3):

First up; no HTML elements should duplicate another element's ID.

Second, because of that the events are only targeting a specific set of elements, notably the first element that has that ID. I would consider moving to a different strategy:

```
<input type="text" value="0" id="text1">

<a href="#" class="minusLink" data-target="text1">Minus</a>
```

And then you can target your script like so:

```
$('.minusLink').click(function()
{
   var target = $('#' + $(this).data('target'));

   target.val(parseInt(target.val(), 10) - 1);
});
```

Comment: This seems like overkill, considering his code would work fine with classes.  This code is definitely more robust, but for what he is doing, I don't think it is strictly necessary.

Comment: Agreed... and switching from ids to classes works just fine, thanks a lot to both

Answer (score 1):

you should reference classes instead of ids because as you see selection by id only retrives first match

Answer (score 1):

An ID on an element can only occur once.  Instead, change ID to class.